# C# My player (the white box) does a jiggle when in contact with the ground after adding the parent control to a moving platform

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

After exiting the collider and in contact with the ground my character jiggles in the ground.
the project is 2d

The lines I added for this problem to occur are these.

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if(other.tag == "MovePtl")
        {
            transform.SetParent(other.transform);
        }
    }
    private void OnTriggerExit(Collider2D other)
    {
        if(other.tag == "MovePtl")
        {
            transform.SetParent(null);
        }
    }
```

this is the full script of the player

```
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * speed, rb.velocity.y);

        isGrounded = Physics2D.OverlapArea(groundPoints[0].position, groundPoints[1].position, groundMask);

        if (isGrounded == true)
        {

            if (currentJumps != 0)
            {
                currentJumps = 0;
            }

            if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
            {
                currentJumps++;
                rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, 0);
                rb.AddForce(Vector2.up * jumpForce);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && currentJumps < totalJumps)
            {
                rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, 0);
                rb.AddForce(Vector2.up * jumpForce);
                currentJumps++;
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if(other.tag == "MovePtl")
        {
            transform.SetParent(other.transform);
        }
    }
    private void OnTriggerExit(Collider2D other)
    {
        if(other.tag == "MovePtl")
        {
            transform.SetParent(null);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the full script of the moving platform

```
public class MovePlatform : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform platform;
    public Transform parentPoints;
    List<Transform> points = new List<Transform>();
    int currentPoint;
    public float speed;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        currentPoint = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < parentPoints.childCount; i++)  // for es un loop donde se declara un iterador que debe cumplir una condicion y cada vez que se cumple el loop el iterador cambiaI = iterador,
        {
            points.Add(parentPoints.GetChild(i));
        }
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        platform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(platform.position, points[currentPoint].position, speed * Time.deltaTime);
        if(platform.position == points[currentPoint].position)
        {
            currentPoint++;
            if(currentPoint >= points.Count)
            {
                currentPoint = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The platform has 2 points in total
the collider of the moving platform is in top of the paltform and thae player clearly exits the collider,
The player collider is the same but is under the player

I want to stop the jiggle that occurs afterwards
No idea if it is a programming issue or a unity one. there is no art in the project only box sprites

Answer (score 0):

Set the Collision Detection mode on your Rigidbody2D to Continuous instead of Discrete.